# Using a lastInsertId() value to populate a column in another table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called player and after inserting the data into there, which successfully works, I have the following piece of code to capture the value of the auto incremented primary key.

```
$one = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

What I then wish to do is to take the value that is stored in this variable and insert it as a value in another table.  I have tried a couple of ways but to no avail.  Please see below:

**ATTEMPT ONE**

```
try
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO links SET
            link = :link,
            playerid = '$one'";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':link', $_POST['link']);
    $s->bindValue(':playerid', $_POST[':playerid']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding link for player.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

**ATTEMPT TWO**

```
try
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO links SET
            link = :link,
            playerid = :playerid';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':link', $_POST['link']);
    $s->bindValue(':playerid', $_POST['$one']);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error adding link for player.' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

The code doesn't actually throw any errors but when I look in the database, the value is not getting passed in.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong please?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: why would `$one` be in `$_POST`?

Comment: Ermmmmmmmm I'm not sure why I thought that would work?  So the $_POST array is automatically created and used to collect values when a form is sent with method='post'. Clearly this value has not come from the submitted form.  I did actually try a number of different ways to do this, think I was just getting desperate and hadn't taken the time to read the code properly.  Thanks for making me take the time to assess why this wouldn't work.

Comment: no problem - I would have answered the same as @Mihai lorga, give his answer a try and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `$one`

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO links SET
        link = :link,
        playerid = :playerid';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':link', $_POST['link']);
$s->bindValue(':playerid', $one);
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai and jammypeach, that works nicely and I now understand why.